# ¿Como puedo mostrar una peticion Ajax POST en el HTML?

Tags: jquery, post, foreach, restful

he intentado de todo para poder mostrar un POST en HTML con un APIrest de reqres.in intentando poner los datos que introduzca el usuario en los inputs en un cuadro pero me ha parecido particularmente dificil.

Me gustaria que los datos que introduzca el usuario aparecieran dentro del cuadro de #caja, pero a pesar de todo me sigue apareciendo el siguiente mensaje de error en la consola:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at Object.success (ajax.js:35)

HTML:

```
<form action="https://reqres.in/api/users" method="POST" id="formulario">
        <p>
            Nombre: <input type="text" name="name">
        </p>
        <p>
            Web: <input type="text" name="web">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Registrar" id="submit">
        </p>
    </form>
    <span id="aviso">Usuario Registrado con Exito</span>
    <div id="datos">

    </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#formulario").click(function(response){
        response.preventDefault();

        var usuario = {
            "nombre": $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            "web": $('input[name="web"]').val()
        }

        $.post($(this).attr("action"), usuario, function(response){
            console.log(response);

        usuario.response.forEach(function(element){
                $("#datos").append("<ul><li><p>"+element+"</p></li></ul>");
        });
        return false;
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero que nada debemos conocer que respuesta te devuelve el servicio *https://reqres.in/api/users* y haciendo un par de pruebas la respuesta es la siguiente:

```
{
    "nombre": "Juan",
    "web": "www.google.com",
    "id": "578",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-24T23:24:47.951Z"
}
```

Ahora, por cómo lo veo, deberías trabajar con el objeto de respuesta que obtienes como resultado (el que vemos arriba que tiene 4 propiedades).

Por otro lado, el error del *forEach* es por que en primer lugar la propiedad *usuario.response* es **undefined** ya que el objeto *usuario* no tiene dicha propiedad y la sentencia *forEach*  no puede iterar sobre una propiedad no definida.

Por último, la información que deberias mostrar dentro del div podría ser algo como:

```js
var datos = $('<ul></ul>');
var name = $('<li></li>').text(response.nombre).appendTo(datos);
var name = $('<li></li>').text(response.web).appendTo(datos);
var name = $('<li></li>').text(response.id).appendTo(datos);
$("#datos").append(datos);
```

Saludos.